# Add values and keys to session and store each individual addition (php)

Tags: php

I am at my wits end for last three days.
What i want to do is to code shopping-cart like functionality. So, i have two inputs that i want EACH to store in its own array. 
something along the lines of:

```
<?php
session_start();

$input1 = [];
$input2 = [];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $input1 = $_POST['first'];
  $input2 = $_POST['second'];

  $_SESSION['test'] = [
    'first' => array_push($input1),
    'second' => array_push($input2)
  ];
}

var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>
```

and my html is as follows :

```
<form  method="post">
  <input type="text" name="first" value="">
  <input type="text" name="second" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="array">
</form>
```

Now i expect the output of var_dump to be as follows:

```
Array(
 [First] => ('Random1','Random2')
 [Second] => ('Flower1','Flower2')
)
```

But what i get in the best case is:

```
Array(
 [First] => Random1
 [Second] => Flower1
 [0] => Random2
 [1] => Flower2
)
```

So, my question is 1) How can i add values to $_SESSION['test'] as an array
and 2) How can i store each input in it's corresponding array?

Comment: So your submit is using `name="array"` yet your using `isset($_POST['submit']`... this shoud be `isset($_POST['array']` just to get you started....

Comment: What about `$_SESSION['test']['first'][] = $input1` and the same for the second? Pay attention that first and second are arrays and already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_push` takes at least two parameters: an array, and something to push into it. You're giving it the one input, and then are not pushing anything into it. Further, you're replacing your entire `$_SESSION['test']` on every run, overwriting it with new (nonsense) values.

What you want is:

```
$_SESSION['test']['first'][] = $input1;
$_SESSION['test']['second'][] = $input2;
```

Append something to the end of the existing arrays, not overwrite them.

Comment: I understand what you said @deceze and Cronos87, but i don't know how to implement your answer :(
i edited array naming as per Option's observation.

Comment: Replace the lines where you're trying to assign to `$_SESSION` with my two lines above. Done.